# Solving for $x$ when $x$ is the denominator

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do you solve for $x$ when $x$ is in the denominator?

E.g.

$$10 = \frac{g-1}{x}$$

Comment: (g-1)/10 = x....

Comment: If there is no $x$ in the numerator, just flip both sides over so that $x$ is where you like it to be: $\frac{1}{10}=\frac{x}{g-1}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zillions of undergraduates with no interest in mathematics but a fair amount of interest in "surviving" required math courses will reflexively say **"cross-multiply!"**.  And in *this* case, they'd be right.  But maybe they'd miss it because they don't quite see two fractions:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{10}{1} & = \frac{g-1}{x} \\  \\  \\
10x & = 1(g-1)
\end{align}
$$
then divide both sides by $10$.

(Then you have to talk them out of "cross-multiplying" when they see $\dfrac ab - \dfrac cd$ and claim that it's of course equal to $ad - bc$, etc.)

Comment: How about when we have x-3/1 = y/x+2?

Comment: @methusaleh : In standard usage, $x-3/1=y/x-2$ means $x-(3/1)=(y/x)-2$, but I've been around enough to hesitate before answering and ask first whether you mean that or $(x-3)/1=y/(x-2)$?  (If the latter, then that's how you should write it.  Either that or $\dfrac{x-3}{1}=\dfrac{y}{x-2}$.)

Comment: @methusaleh: ...and if you _do_ mean $x-\frac 31=\frac yx-2$, first write both sides with a common denominator (i.e. $\frac{x-3}1=\frac{y-2x}x$) and then cross-multiply. (Or just multiply both sides with $x$; multiplying or dividing by 1 makes no difference anyway.)

Answer (score 9):

You can use the technique of "clearing denominators". To do so, just multiply both sides of the equation by whatever denominator you wish to get rid of.
$$
\begin{align*}
10 &= \frac{g-1}{x}\\
10 \cdot x &= \frac{g-1}{x} \cdot x\\
10x &= g-1.
\end{align*}
$$
No matter how many denominators there are, you can use this trick to clear them all. Now you have a much simpler equation to work with.

Comment: However, note that this technique can introduce spurious solutions.  For example, if $g=1$, the original equation has no solution, even though the rewritten version has the solution $x=0$.  Always check that the solutions you get actually satisfy the original equation.

Comment: Y'all make this look so easy!!!! I think my head id going to fall off!